# query sqlite: add figures any numbers and another

Tags: sqlite

I've a table "mytable" like this:

[MyTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Itr.jpg)

I would like to add the figures of each number with the condition that: 
if the add is > 9 you subtract 9.

Ex. 13 = 1 + 3= 4 
7 = 0 + 7 = 7 
 55= 5 + 5=10 - 9 = 1 
 27 = 9

Code: 
select number%9 from mytable

But, in this case, for the value 27 return 0, not 9 (value correct).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question by showing us nicely formatted tables.  Please do this before your question gets voted off.

Comment: Are you sure it's >9 and not ≥9?

Comment: Yes: >9. The expected and possible results are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), so your result will be in the set `[0...(x-1)]`, where `x` is your divisor.  You want to shift your result set to be `[1...x]`, but not shifting everything up one.  Instead, you want the result to be the "normal" mod result unless that result is zero, in which case you want to return your divisor.  To do this, we'll need a case statement...

```
SELECT
     CASE WHEN (number % 9) = 0 THEN
          9
     ELSE
          (number % 9)
     END AS [field]
FROM
     mytable
```

Comment: @Andreas I'm not following.  I went by your comment to the OP: _The expected and possible results are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9_ .  What does _4.7.1.9_ represent?

Comment: Hi. For all numbers from 1 to 90 The expected and possible results are: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 . It was just to generalize. Returning to the practical case, for the number 13*7*55*27 the result of add figures expected= 4*7*1*9. The query ... select number%9 return 4.7.1.0. How do you convert zero in 9?

Comment: Thank you. It's perfect, LDMJoe

Comment: @Andreas I think I see what you're after now.  For the input of 13, your desired result is 4.  For the input of 7, your desired result is 7.  For the input of 55, your desired result is 1.  For the input of 27, your desired result is 9.  Based on this understanding, I've edited the answer accordingly.